# Javascript - how to access object attribute in an event function?

Tags: javascript, html, events, web

I am a newbie programmer. I want to create my script in OO way. However I can't think of how to protect my properties and still be able to access it. The problem is that I cant access my `this.XXX` properties in the function

```
this.handleStartEvent=function(event)
```

The error message in Firebug:

> "TypeError: this.imgContainer is undefined"

The whole script is below:

```
var imageViewer=function(imageWrapper)
{
    var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window,
    resizeEvent = 'onorientationchange' in window ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize',
    startEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
    moveEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    endEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup',
    cancelEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchcancel' : 'mouseup';

    this.imgContainer=imageWrapper;
    this.image=imageWrapper.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    this.initScale=1;
    this.scaleLevel=this.initScale;
    this.startPoint={x:0,y:0}

    //alert(this.image)
    this.initEvents=function()
    {
        window.addEventListener(resizeEvent, this.resizeImageViewer, false);
        this.imgContainer.addEventListener(startEvent, this.handleStartEvent, false);
        this.imgContainer.addEventListener(moveEvent, this.handleMoveEvent, false);
        this.imgContainer.addEventListener(endEvent, this.handleEndEvent, false);
    }

    this.resizeImageViewer=function(event)
    {
        /*not finish*/
    }

    this.handleStartEvent=function(event)
    {
        /**********problem goes here*************/
        this.startPoint.x = event.offsetX || (event.pageX - this.imgContainer.offsetLeft); 
        this.startPoint.y = event.offsetY || (event.pageY - this.imgContainer.offsetTop);
    }

    this.handleMoveEvent=function(event)
    {
        /*not finish*/
    }

    this.handleEndEvent=function()
    {
        /*not finish*/
    }

    this.initEvents();
}

var imageViewerObj = new imageViewer(document.getElementById("imageWrapper"));
```

I know that `this` will be the `imgContainer`, not the `imageViewer`, but I don't know how to get my `imageViewer`'s properties like `startPoint` and `initScale`. Could someone guide me a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep reference to `this` just save it in other variable:

```
var imageViewer = function(imageWrapper)
{
    var self = this; // use "self" instead of "this" later

    ...

    self.startPoint={x:0,y:0}

    self.initEvents=function()
    {
        window.addEventListener(resizeEvent, self.resizeImageViewer, false);
        self.imgContainer.addEventListener(startEvent, self.handleStartEvent, false);
        self.imgContainer.addEventListener(moveEvent, self.handleMoveEvent, false);
        self.imgContainer.addEventListener(endEvent, self.handleEndEvent, false);
    }

    ...

    self.initEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If imgContainer is the parent then you can use `this.parent.getAttribute(...);` if its a child `this.parent.getChildAt( index ).getAttribute(...);`

Replace index with the number (index) of the element you want to select. If its first child like `<div><div class="wannaselectthat"></div></div>` set index to zero.

Comment: I am sorry that I make some misunderstanding on the word "attribute".I want to get imageViewer's object variables like startPoint, initScale in the this.handleStartEvent function. Thank for answering.

Comment: this.parent.getChildAt( index ).attr would work fine. like this.parent.getChildAt( index ).id